# Logstash stops receiving after some time in ELK stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have ELK stack (Elasticsearch/Logstash/Kibana) installed and running.

I use one server as ELK server to collect and store all logs from other servers.
`logstash-forwarder` is used to send logs to ELK. The problem is:

Logstash is receiving alot of logs (as I checked with `tailf logstash.stdout`) but after some period when I `tailf logstash.stdout` again, there are nothing (not receving logs), after restarting the Logstash daemon it begins to receive again.

Comment: What do the logstash logs say? Have you tried not sending so many logs to see if that is actually the cause of your problem?

Comment: @bradvido, thanks for the support, logstash logs is empty, so i tried to reduce the sending logs, then the logstash daemon stay longer time and then i got this error in the logstash.log 
<blink>
"Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 500M.            
Specify -J-Xmx####m to increase it (#### = cap size in MB).                      
Specify -w for full OutOfMemoryError stack trace" </blink>

Comment: another information about the question that may help others to answer me.
when i enter this command `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v'`i got this output 
`host                   ip             heap.percent ram.percent load node.role master name                                       
elasticsearch_node_master xxxxxxx           57          87 0.60 d         *      Death's Head II                            
logstash_node xxxxxx           99                  c         -      logstash-logs.-50227-226`
I think the error is shown here because logstash node use 99 of heap.help please?

Answer (score 1):

when you use Logstash to filter data into files, when Logstash get EOF (end of file) occurs what you said.

If it's like I'm thinking, you can consulte this: [How to return to terminal when logstash filter get eof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552053/how-to-return-to-terminal-when-logstash-filter-get-eof)

In the case of using shippers, maybe works at same as files.

But if you describe better your problem/errors you can get more possible resolutions.